# What is supersede in a DHCP config?

Tags: dhcp

E.g.: what does

```
supersede domain-name "SOMETHING.COM FOO.ORG";
```

exactly mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, *supersede* means (from OED)

> To take the place of (something set aside or abandoned); to succeed to the place occupied by; to serve, be adopted or accepted instead of.

From `man dhclient.conf`

> The supersede statement
>
> ```
>    supersede [ option declaration ] ;
>
>  If  for  some  option the client should always use a locally-configured
>  value or values rather than whatever is supplied by the  server,  these
>  values can be defined in the supersede statement.
> ```

So, for instance, you could write:

```
supersede host-name "myCoolName";
```